# Positioning a picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with positioning the picture. I would like to put it on the left side of a div with .brand class. Here is the code used in the webpage:

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive brand-img" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    <div class="brand">MG STAV</div>    
    <div class="address-bar"> stavební, spol. s.r.o.</div>
</div>

 .brand-img{
   text-align: center;
 }

.brand {
      display: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 30px 0 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 5em;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: normal;
      color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom;` for div with class brand and  `text-align: center;`for .container

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive brand-img" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    <div class="brand">MG STAV</div>
    <div class="address-bar">stavební, spol. s.r.o.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
text-align: center;
}
.brand-img {
    text-align: center;
}
.brand {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 30px 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    font-family:"Josefin Slab", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Check this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm0bnu63/)

Comment: @J Prakash The thing is, that i need to have IMG and both divs in the center of the webpage's width + the logo right in the left of the brand div.

Comment: @user3654045 I have changed my answer according to your requirements , check this out

Answer (score 0):

Set the elements inside the container to "inline-block".

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/fozafufaka/1/edit?css,output

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img-responsive brand-img" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="">
    <div class="brand">MG STAV</div>    
    <div class="address-bar"> stavební, spol. s.r.o.</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  text-align:center;
}

.brand-img{
  display:inline-block
 }

.brand {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 30px 0 10px;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      font-family: "Josefin Slab","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
      font-size: 5em;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: normal;
      color: #fff;
}
```